Passing Return String From Imported Function into Database Using Prisma Create Object
I'm using typescript in a application and created a test to populate a database using Prisma ORM.
I have a function that returns a string.
const mappingPayload = (data: any) => {
let pay = []

const payload = data[0] // 'Hello'
const payloadTwo = data[0] // 'You'

pay.push(`${payloadTwo}`}
pay.push(`${payload}`)

const payRes = 
`${pay[0]},
${pay[1]}`

return  payRes

}


The test looks like this in the beginning:
import {data, mappingPayload } from '../../src/taskHandlers/buildPayload';

describe('Build Payload', () => {
    beforeAll(
        async () => {
            await loadConfig();
            const db = await getDbClient()

            const dataJir =mappingPayload(data)
            
            payload = await db.cadPayload.create({ data: { 

"resource_type": "mixture",
  "number_of_protected_ips": [1, 8],
  "total_inbound_traffic": [0, 50],
  "total_mitigated_traffic": 20,
  "resources_behind": true,
  "package": "alwayson",} 

});



This works as I'm passing raw data straight into the DB.Create object.
However I'd like to pass the function result string into the DB.Create object.
import {data, mappingPayload } from '../../src/taskHandlers/buildPayload';

describe('Build Payload', () => {
    beforeAll(
        async () => {
            await loadConfig();
            const db = await getDbClient()

            const dataJir =mappingPayload(data) //FROM HERE TO-->
            
            payload = await db.cadPayload.create({ data: { dataJir } }); //HERE!



As you can see I'm passing the returning value of the mapping function to the database.
But keep getting this ERROR from my actual test case:
➜  testing git:(pnyeko_feature_pi_CAD_17_3.1) ✗ npm run test buildPayload.test.ts

> ms-cad-worker@1.0.0 test
> jest buildPayload.test.ts

 FAIL  testing/integration/buildPayload.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    testing/integration/buildPayload.test.ts:26:60 - 
error TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, 
and 'dataJir' does not exist in type 
'(Without<cadPayloadCreateInput, 
cadPayloadUncheckedCreateInput> & 
cadPayloadUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & cadPayloadCreateInput)'.

26  payload = await db.cadPayload.create({ data: { dataJir
                                                                  ~~~~~~~
node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:10977:5
10977     data: XOR<cadPayloadCreateInput, cadPayloadUncheckedCreateInput>
                  ~~~~
The expected type comes from property 
'data' which is declared here on type 

'{ select?: cadPayloadSelect 
| null | undefined; data: 
(Without<cadPayloadCreateInput, 
cadPayloadUncheckedCreateInput> & 
cadPayloadUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & cadPayloadCreateInput); }'

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.733 s, estimated 9 s
Ran all test suites matching /buildPayload.test.ts/i.

How does one pass the result of a function that returns a string, into a prisma create object as if it were raw data?

You have a function that returns an array, if that helps. (Kind of an odd way of doing it, but that’s tangential.)

@DaveNewton Made a quick change, thanks for picking up on that. I meant to put the indexes of a array in a const string, so the function returns the value of whats inside the array.

I’m not sure I understand what you think you’re doing. If cadPayload expects an object how would using a string be a thing?

I'm passing the string into an {} object, not sure how to avoid the error?

The contents of an object are properties with values, not a string?

You are correct, thus my question, is how do I pass a string that is in the name/value format into an object in prisma.DB.Create{Function Result} ?

By setting a property value (that makes sense in context) on the object.

(Not an answer, but need space and formatting.)
The shape of the data passed to db.cadPayload.create is this:
{
  data: { 
    "resource_type": "mixture",
    "number_of_protected_ips": [1, 8],
    "total_inbound_traffic": [0, 50],
    "total_mitigated_traffic": 20,
    "resources_behind": true,
    "package": "alwayson",
  },
}

You won't be able to change the data's shape arbitrarily--it has to make sense in the context of whatever cadPayload is.
You're doing this:
{ data: { dataJir } }

which will create { data: { dataJir: [dataJir's value, a string constructed in the most verbose way possible] } } which doesn't match the working cadPayload shape.
If you're trying to modify a value in an object just do so:
const obj = {
  data: { 
    "resource_type": "mixture",
    "number_of_protected_ips": [1, 8],
    "total_inbound_traffic": [0, 50],
    "total_mitigated_traffic": 20,
    "resources_behind": true,
    "package": "alwayson",
  },
}

const s = 'some, string'
obj.data.package = s

const arr = [42, 69]
obj.data.total_inbound_traffic = arr

BUT you can't just pass arbitrary shapes containing arbitrary data to something that expects specific data in a specific shape.

Re: the string function, assuming the re-referencing of index 0 is a typo, and the rewrite was unintentional:
const mappingPayload = (data: any) => {
  let pay = [];

  const payload = data[0] // 'Hello'
  const payloadTwo = data[0] // 'You'

  pay.push(`${payloadTwo}`}
  pay.push(`${payload}`)

  const payRes = `${pay[0]},${pay[1]}`
  return  payRes
}

const fn = (data: any) => `${data[0]},${data[1]}`

(But no good reason to throw away stack info w/ an anonymous function, just use a function.)

This "not matching payload shape" is exactly what happened...I see, you are applying each of the values to the Obj.data name/value const. I will give this a try and pass each Obj.data.name/value to the object like this:  db.cadPayload.create({ data: Obj.data.package, Obj.data.total_inbound_traffic }). Could this be viable? Thank you @DaveNewton

Re: The referencing of [0] was indeed a typo  I made here. I had to replicate the function for data protection reasons, so I made a typo. Its supposed to be const payload = data[0] // 'Hello'
const payloadTwo = data[1] // 'You'....The reason for the re-referencing is because of the re-ordering of the indexes values as printed in the console. For example, const payRes = ${pay[1]},${pay[0]}  came out as You, Hello...So I referenced the data to re-order them in the return string. But now I see that is not necessarily needed.

@PatrickNyeko I’d probably head for a JS tutorial; data/object access and manipulation are fundamental

It worked like a charm! Thank you so much @Dave Newton. I was able to pass a object as a return value to my database using prisma.create({object}). This was my function passed directly: prisma.cadPayload.create({ mappingPayload(JirraPayload).data }). All test passing finally! Yes, I've learned a big lesson here in data/object access and manipulation and I'll pick some tutorials to understand it more.

That’s great—glad you worked it out
